# How to edit custom CSS styles of Chrome devtools UI?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, console.log

I want to customize how Chrome devtools console looks. (In particular, I want to limit the width of script filename / line number which is printed next to each console.log output, and which is inconveniently long when I use tampermonkey userscripts.)
[image]

I know that chrome devtools is a web app itself, and I can inspect it and view its HTML elements and their CSS styles.
[image]

But how can I edit these CSS styles such that I could save my edits persistently? Are there their CSS files somewhere on my computer which I can edit and save?

Comment: You'll need to write a chrome extension that sets a devtools theme. Download one from the web store, remove `_metadata` and adapt its code to your needs, then load it in unpacked mode.